# how to pass a value through Link in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to pass the `first: 1` through a link in react js but I am not getting it how to do it. What I have tried is below.

```
let first = 1;

  <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/sign",
          state: { variable: 1 },
        }}
      >
        <div className="box">i am pregent</div>
      </Link>
```

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/sign" name="routename" element={Sign}></Route>
</Routes>
```

```
export default class Sign extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // this.state = { variable: props.location.state.variable };
    const { variable = "defaultValue" } = props.location.state
      ? props.location.state
      : {};
    console.log(variable);
```

Comment: state just pass to Sign component , you cant get it from App class component

Comment: @KhanhLeTran are u the one closed this question the answer does not help me i am looking for better answers so i ask u to repoen this question let others help me

Comment: No , moderator do that , not me. Your question is duplicated. You can get the answer below your title or ref this link https://ui.dev/react-router-pass-props-to-link . Try to use useLocation.

Comment: What part of the duplicate didn't answer your question? It covers passing data via a link and accessing it in a receiving component. Check the `react-router-dom@6` sections. For your code, pass the data on the `Link` component's `state` prop, and to access it in the `Sign` component you'll need to create a custom `withRouter` HOC that uses the `useLocation` hook to access `location.state` and pass it in props to `Sign`. It's all in the post.

Comment: i have tryed everthing in the  link it doesnot woek for me i am passing varaible from a lfuntion compoent to a class componet can u help me with a anwer so i can try @DrewReese

Comment: Please [edit] your post with what you have tried applying from the duplicate post and provide more details about what specifically isn't working. My previous comment is what you should be working on.

Comment: @DrewReese as u can see in the question i am trying to pass from a funtional compoent to a class compeont and i have tyred  location.state in class componet

Comment: I can see that. Like I said, the `Link` component has a `state` prop, i.e. `<Link to="/sign" state={{ variable: 1 }}>...</Link>`, and to access the passed state in a React Class component you'll need to create a custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component that uses the `useLocation` hook and passed `location` as a prop to the decorated component. The duplicate explains all of this.

Comment: how to use  withRouter  & withRouter in a class compoent a answer explaining this will be helpfull so i can try what you are sugesting